# MS Word 2019 not displaying Hindi Text in Thumbnail

Tags: microsoft-word, unicode

I have a word 2019 with Hindi(Unicode), Urdu(Unicode), Arabic, English text in it; when I save I also check the 'save thumbnail' option but in the thumbnail all three languages show the text except
Hindi (display as question marks)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQjCE.png)

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. I tried to install Hindi language package for Windows 10, install different Hindi fonts and apply these font to Hindi text. The issue still occurred as well. I also referred to  [Choose text encoding when you open and save files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-text-encoding-when-you-open-and-save-files-60d59c21-88b5-4006-831c-d536d42fd861), I can't fix it. I suggest you can [give a feedback on this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-do-i-give-feedback-on-microsoft-office-2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11).